# Angular JS form validation using ModelState in Web API Core

Tags: angularjs, validation, asp.net-web-api, typescript, asp.net-core

I am working on a Web Application with client side in AngularJS, TypeScript and HTML, and the server side is a .NET Core Web API.

I want to implement server side validation using ModelState and DTOs. The thing is that I don't want to display all the validation errors at the top of the Form, but I want to display them in-line with the textbox

[image]

So first I added the validations to a DTO and then checking in the controller for `ModelState.IsValid`

```
public class TestDTO
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string TestName { get; set; }
}

public class ManyTestDTO
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Many Item is required")]
    public string ManyItem { get; set; }
}

public class RestaurantDTO
{
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required"), MaxLength(20), MinLength(1)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public TestDTO TestModel { get; set; }

    public List<ManyTestDTO> TestMany { get; set; }

    public RestaurantDTO()
    {
    }

}
```

Getting the idea from this link: [Link](http://www.danielroot.info/2013/09/hooking-angularjs-validation-to-aspnet.html) - I have created a directive in my Application to display the validation message in-line, it is working fine the problem is that the HTML I am writing to show the validation message is  complex.

The Directive

```
export class ServerValidationDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    constructor() { }
    restrict: "A";
    require: "ngModel";

    link = function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

        scope.$watch("controller.modelState", () => {

            let modelState = scope.controller.modelState;

            console.log(modelState);

            if (modelState == null) return;

            let state = modelState[attrs.ngServerValidate];

            if (state) {
                // Server Errors exist for the ngServerValidate
                scope.controller.parsedModelState[attrs.ngServerValidate] = state;
            } else {
                // No Error for the ngServerValidate
                if (scope.controller.parsedModelState[attrs.ngServerValidate]) {
                    scope.controller.parsedModelState[attrs.ngServerValidate] = null;
                }
            }

        });
    };

    static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        var directive = () => new ServerValidationDirective();
        return directive;
    }
}
```

The Controller:

```
class CreateRestaurantController {

    static $inject = ["$scope"];

    restaurantModel: any;
    modelState: any;
    parsedModelState: any;
    testModelState:any;


    constructor($scope) {
        this.scope = $scope; // create a local copy of the $scope
        this.scope.controller = this; //put controller reference in this.scope.controller

        this.restaurantModel = {name: "Dawood",testModel: {},testMany: [{ ManyItem: "I have a Value" },{}]};
        this.modelState = null;
        this.parsedModelState = {};

        this.testModelState = JSON
            .parse('{"Address":["This field is required"],"Description":["This field is required"],"TestModel.TestName":["This field is required"],"TestMany[1].ManyItem":["Many Item is required"]}');

        console.log(this.testModelState);
    }


    testValidation() {

        this.modelState = this.testModelState;
        //Normally modelStae  will be return from server

        // Submit to Server

        //this.apiService.post("/api/RestaurantDashboard/GetTestValidation",
        //    null, this.restaurantModel,
        //    response => {
        //        console.log(response);
        //    },
        //    response => {
        //        this.modelState = response.data;
        //    });
    }
}
```

The HTML for the Form

```
<div ng-app="validationApp">

  <div ng-controller="validationController">

    <form name="restaurantForm" class="form">

      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': controller.parsedModelState.Name != null}">
        <label>Restaurant Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-server-validate="Name" ng-model="controller.restaurantModel.name">
        <span class="help-block" ng-repeat="errorMessage in controller.parsedModelState.Name"> {{errorMessage}} </span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': controller.parsedModelState.Address != null}">
        <label>Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-server-validate="Address" ng-model="controller.restaurantModel.address">
        <span class="help-block" ng-repeat="errorMessage in controller.parsedModelState.Address"> {{errorMessage}} </span>
      </div>

      <h3>Nested Object</h3>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': controller.parsedModelState['TestModel.TestName'] != null}">
        <label>TestModel.TestName</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-server-validate="TestModel.TestName" ng-model="controller.restaurantModel.testModel.testName">
        <span class="help-block" ng-repeat="errorMessage in controller.parsedModelState['TestModel.TestName']"> {{errorMessage}} </span>
      </div>


      <h3>Many Array/List</h3>

      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="item in controller.restaurantModel.testMany">
          <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': controller.parsedModelState['TestMany[' + $index + '].ManyItem'] != null}">
            <label>Many Item {{$index}}</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-server-validate="{{'TestMany[' + $index + '].ManyItem'}}" ng-model="item.ManyItem">
            <span class="help-block" ng-repeat="errorMessage in controller.parsedModelState['TestMany[' + $index + '].ManyItem']"> {{errorMessage}} </span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="controller.testValidation()">Click Me to Check</button>

    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

As you can see the HTML structure for the `Many Array/List` and `Nested Object` is a bit complex. Is there a better way to do this?

## Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mdawood1991/ua9mk7qz/

Comment: Have you checked ng-messages ? 
Here is an Example : https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages

Comment: I would recommend you to implement your form validation in the client-side (angularjs). Then, you create another validation in the server-side (asp.net core). The angularjs validation is important to provide a nice user experience and avoid unnecessary POSTs to the server. But, the asp.net core validation is the important one, because a smart user can hack your client-side validation, but cannot do the same with your server-side validation.

Comment: I do also agree with fabricio, use angular for clientside and fluent-validator for server side validations. Fluent validator also works with angular, the kind of validation that you are after